# Averaging column values by several intervals in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with depth and other value columns:

```
data = {'Depth': [1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0], 
'Value1':[44, 46, 221, 12, 47, 44, 67, 90, 100, 111, 112, 120, 122], 
'Value2': [55, 65, 76, 45, 55, 58, 23, 12, 32, 20, 22, 26, 36]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

As you can see sometime there are repetitions in the `Depth`.

I'd like to be able to somehow groupby intervals and average over them.
For example an output I desire would be:

```
intervals = [1.0, 2.0]
```

Taking a list of intervals and breaking up the data set on those intervals to average **per value (Value1, Value2)** to get:

```
    Depth  Value1  Value2   Avg1_1  Avg2_1  Avg1_2   Avg2_2   
0     1.0      44      55   80.75   60.25   78.2     .
1     1.0      46      65   80.75   60.25   78.2     .
2     1.5     221      76   80.75   60.25   78.2     .
3     2.0      12      45   80.75   60.25   78.2
4     2.5      47      55   52.67   .       78.2
5     2.5      44      58   52.67   .       78.2
6     3.0      67      23   52.67   .       78.2 
7     3.5      90      12   100.33          78.2
8     4.0     100      32   100.33          78.2
9     4.0     111      20   100.33          78.2
10    5.0     112      22   112             .
11    5.5     120      26   121             .
12    6.0     122      36   121             .
```

Where Avg1_ is the Average of `Value1` over every interval of `1.0` (which includes (1.0 - 2.0, 2.5 - 3.0,....etc).

Is there an easy way to do this using `groupby` in a loop?

Comment: You can do with cut , but you need to show us the edge , like 1 ,2 both of them into first interval so [1,2] but next interval become (2,3]?

Comment: The cuts would be on intervals (1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0) for the interval 1.0 calculations.

Comment: nope in your show case the boundary is contain within one interval like 1&2 are in same interval which is no trend for create by code

Comment: And also 1.0 and 2.0 belong to one interval , why 5.0 5.5 and 6.0 not in the same interval

Comment: My mistake. It would be (1.0, 2.0], (2.5, 3.0]....etc

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the dataframe's `apply` method, and then sampling by boolean values the rows (and associated values) that meet the condition like `depth + 1.0` or `depth + 2.0`.

```
df['avg1_1'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 1.0]['Value1'].values.sum() / 
                                          len(df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 1.0]['Value1'].values)),
                                            axis=1)

df['avg2_1'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 1.0]['Value2'].values.sum() / 
                                  len(df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 1.0]['Value2'].values)),
                                    axis=1)

df['avg1_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 2.0]['Value1'].values.sum() / 
                                  len(df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 2.0]['Value1'].values)),
                                    axis=1)

df['avg2_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 2.0]['Value2'].values.sum() / 
                                  len(df[df['Depth'] <= x['Depth'] + 2.0]['Value2'].values)),
                                    axis=1)
```

This would return:

```
Depth   Value1  Value2  newval  avg1_1  avg2_1  avg1_2  avg2_2
0   1.0 44  55  66.0    80.750000   60.250000   68.714286   53.857143
1   1.0 46  65  241.0   80.750000   60.250000   68.714286   53.857143
2   1.5 221 76  32.0    69.000000   59.000000   71.375000   48.625000
3   2.0 12  45  67.0    68.714286   53.857143   78.200000   44.100000
4   2.5 47  55  64.0    71.375000   48.625000   78.200000   44.100000
5   2.5 44  58  87.0    71.375000   48.625000   78.200000   44.100000
6   3.0 67  23  110.0   78.200000   44.100000   81.272727   42.090909
7   3.5 90  12  120.0   78.200000   44.100000   84.500000   40.750000
8   4.0 100 32  131.0   81.272727   42.090909   87.384615   40.384615
9   4.0 111 20  132.0   81.272727   42.090909   87.384615   40.384615
10  5.0 112 22  140.0   87.384615   40.384615   87.384615   40.384615
11  5.5 120 26  142.0   87.384615   40.384615   87.384615   40.384615
12  6.0 122 36  NaN 87.384615   40.384615   87.384615   40.384615
```